# How do I calculate a column value based on the existin columns

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

```
create table myTable (int i, int user_id, int a, int b, int c)
```

The values are like this.

```
1, 1, 1, 1, 0
2, 1, 2, 2, 0
3, 2, 3, 3, 0
4, 2, 4, 4, 0
```

I want column "c" to be updated as "a" + "b" for user_id = 1. How should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select query

```
 SELECT a, b, (a+b) AS c FROM mytable where user_id=1;
```

UPDATE query

```
 UPDATE mytable SET c = a+b where user_id=1;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
update myTable set c = a+b where user_id =1;
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bafcff/1)

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**For a particular record:**

```
update some_table set `c` = (`a`+`b`) where `user_id` = your_id;
```

**For all:**

```
update some_table set `c` = (`a`+`b`);
```